# Derivation of the expectation of exponential random variable

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-distribution

I am following some course notes for the expectation of an exponential random variable, $X \sim \text{Expon}(\mu)$. I believe this is a correct derivation:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X]
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} x \mu e^{-\mu x} dx
\\\\
&= \mu \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-\mu x} dx
\\\\
&= \mu \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d \mu} -e^{-\mu x} dx
\\\\
&= -\mu \frac{d}{d \mu} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\mu x} dx
\\\\
&= -\mu \frac{d}{d \mu} \frac{1}{\mu}
\\\\
&= \frac{1}{\mu}
\end{align}
$$

where we used the facts that

$$
x e^{-\mu x} = \frac{d}{d \mu} - e^{-\mu x}
$$

and

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\mu x} dx = \frac{1}{\mu}
$$

What I don't follow is the second fact. I would have used [calculus rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_only_exponential_functions) to compute

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\mu x} dx = \frac{1}{- \mu} e^{- \mu x} + C
$$

What am I missing?

Comment: This is just a "trick" method.  It works as a clever manipulation, but, most people would not actually compute it this way. The standard way is integration by parts. An alternative way is to use the formula for nonnegative random variables $X\geq 0$ that $E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P[X>x]dx$.

Comment: I notice your actual question at the bottom, you are doing it correctly but you are missing a final step:  you found an antiderivative $F(x)$ of $e^{-\mu x}$ (so $F'(x) = e^{-\mu x}$) and now you must evaluate it over the limits of integration $F(\infty) -F(0) = (-1/\mu)e^{-\mu x}|_0^{\infty} = 0 - (-1/\mu) = 1/\mu$.  Recall that $$\int_a^b F'(x)dx = F(x)|_a^b=F(b)-F(a)$$ So $$ \int_0^{\infty} F'(x)dx = F(\infty)-F(0)$$ where $F(\infty) = \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} F(b)$.

Comment: @Michael: Granted most people would not have done it this way, but Feynman would have. :-)  (See "[Integration: The Feynman Way](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf).")

Comment: @BrianTung : Would Feynman also have justified passing the derivative with respect to $\mu$ through the integral with respect to $x$?

Comment: Yeah, the teacher mentioned that integration by parts is how it would be done in most calculus courses. But your second comment answers my question. Thanks,

Comment: @Michael: I don't know, but my *guess* is that while he was doing this most of the time, he wasn't terribly rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a formal summary of my comments above, with some detail. Recall the difference between an *indefinite integral* $\int f(x)dx$ and *definite integral* $\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

- Indefinite integral:  $\int e^{-\mu x}dx = \frac{-1}{\mu} e^{-\mu x} + c$
- Definite integral : $\int_a^b e^{-\mu x}dx = (\frac{-1}{\mu} e^{-\mu x} + c)|_a^b = \frac{-1}{\mu}e^{-\mu b} - \frac{-1}{\mu}e^{-\mu a}$

Notice that the $+c$ cancels out when taking the difference.  So we can use *any* antiderivative and we might as well use $c=0$.

---

On computing $E[X]$ via integration by parts:

$$\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)g(x)] = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) \implies \boxed{\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b f'(x)g(x)dx}$$

So
$$ E[X]=\int_0^{\infty} \underbrace{x}_{f(x)} \underbrace{\mu e^{-\mu x}}_{g'(x)}dx = f(x)g(x)|_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} \underbrace{f'(x)}_{1}\underbrace{g(x)}_{-e^{-\mu x}}dx $$
and 
$$ f(x)g(x)|_0^{\infty} = (-xe^{-\mu x})|_0^{\infty} = \left(\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} -be^{-\mu b}\right) - 0 = 0$$